# How to fix 'ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pillow' error in pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to install pyqt5 using pipenv.

This error appears in pipenv shelll.

ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pillow.

[Wrong here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXYuM.png)

I have tried running the following commands suggest[pipenv install --skip-lock and pipenv lock -clear] but I still get the same error.

```
(PYQT5-oLhRixBB) D:\PYQT5>pipenv install pyqt5
Installing pyqt5…
Adding pyqt5 to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Locking Failed!
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/Hasee/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\Hasee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\Hasee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\Hasee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pillow
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pillow
No versions found
Was http://pypi.douban.com/simple reachable?
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\Hasee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\Hasee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\Hasee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pillow
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pillow
No versions found
Was http://pypi.douban.com/simple reachable?
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact commands you tried? And have you tried to `pipenv install pillow`?

Comment: I tried pipenv install pillow and it was the same .

Comment: Have you tried running it as root?

Comment: Because I'm running Windows, I tried to run as an administrator

Comment: I don't really know pipenv, but wouldn't it be great to post your pipfile?